# Make shape from shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm completely new to illustrator and there's one thing I can't figure out. Here's an image

[image]

I drew a shape, I then drew a line from the inside top to inside bottom (which I guess was another shape, but with fill turned off), what I want is for the area on the right (which I have put red lines through to show) to be it's own separate shape, how do I do that?

I've used Flash for many years, and in Flash this takes 5 seconds. You draw the line, connect the start/end point and that's it you have a new shape cut into 2 parts, but I can't see how you do that in Illustrator CC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half a second in Illustrator.....

draw a line.... select all... click the **Divide** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**